# Autodeploy property files in Java Web projects from NetBeans

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, properties-file, hotdeploy

I am developing a Java EE webapp with NetBeans 8.0.

For the internationalization of my app I am using property files stored in "src\main\resources". If I run my project on my local GlassFish (connected with NetBeans), then changes in Java and XHTML files will be compiled as I save them and auto-deployed to my GlassFish.

But If I make changes to my property files (*.properties), then these changes will not appear in my deployed webapp. I have to clean & build my project and run it again, before I can see them.

Is there any way to have also auto-deployment for property files in NetBeans?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to have also auto-deployment for property files in
>   NetBeans?

It is already enabled by default. This should work in the same way as with Java or XHTML files. If it doesn't, there might be a problem with your project structure, although the path where you put the files is OK.

To make sure the problem is not in your project structure, you can install NetBeans 7.4 and import your project to test if autodeployment works there.